# Crossdomain file edit

Tags: php

I need to know, where from is my script used (it's for sale, and i don't want any thiefs).
I want to write on my server in file, IP of user, domain where from script has been runned, date, etc. I've tried fopen, fwrite, but is_file_writable returned that it isn't. File CHmods are 777, it parent catalog has too 777 chmods.

Now i'm trying something like that:

```
<?php
$file = 'http://www.misiur.com/security/seal.txt';

$data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$svr = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$str = "[$data] Loaded by $ip at $svr\r\n";

$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $str;
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

However - nothing happens. What i've got to do?

Comment: HTTP is at it's core a file **retrieval** system, not a file publishing system. There are various extensions to HTTP that do allow it, but I don't think you can utilise them from PHP in quite this fashion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP URL wrapper [doesn't allow writing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

The best way to do this would be having a script on the remote server's end (in your example, `misiur.com`:

```
http://www.misiur.com/security/write_seal.php
```

Send the contents of the new text file to that script using POST. The script would then `file_put_contents()` the received information *locally*.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php#80435)'s a code snippet that allows you to send POST contents to remote scripts easily.  You will need POST because GET is usually limited in size to 1-2 kilobytes.

Of course, you would need to secure that script somehow to prevent malicious use, e.g. through a `.htaccess` based password protection or a passkey.